# Metrics for when to use a hash value?

Tags: c#, architecture, visual-studio, vb.net, hashing

I am working on a project that requires a series of flat files. I will be doing some data checking against simple date like:

ID;StatusCode

So a typical file might be like:

```
13993;R
38293;A
19349;I
```

How do you decide if it makes sense to turn these values into a hash or if it makes more sense to just do straight string checking?

I'm really asking a theoretical question here for determining architecture. So the language shouldn't matter. But for the sake of the question, let's just say that I'm going to do this in VB.NET or one of the other .NET languages.

For the most part I'll be taking values from one file and comparing if the value exists in another file. So I'll most likely be using a List object (two of them, one from each file) and then use LINQ or just a straight iteration through.

Does it make sense to use a hash when the strings are this short? Does it depend more on the volume of the data?

Comment: It would help if you could clarify what kind of data checking you're going to be doing.  Are you looking for duplicate entries or just trying to validate what's there?

Comment: There's a tip-over point where the overhead of comparing a number of strings exceeds the overhead of computing a single hash and retrieving the correct value from the hash table.    It would be easy enough to test with a couple dozen lines of code.

Comment: There is a micro-benchmark [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-time) comparing the performance of a list search vs. a hashtable.  The tip-over point is much lower than I would have expected; this benchmark suggest that you should switch to a hashtable *when your list exceeds 3 items in size.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've reproduced that micro-benchmark in LinqPad, and noticed that (1) if you `String.Intern` the strings first, and so use VB.NET's `Is` (or C#'s `(object)=`) you only increase the tip-over point to 5 and (2) if you don't need to otherwise access the list by index, using `LinkedList` increases the tip-over point to 6 (for normal `String =`) and about 34 for Interned Strings with `Is`. What caused me to check the `LinkedList` was using `DotLisp.Cons`, with an API designed for interactive interpreter with `Object` functions had tip-overs at about 5 (`=`)  and about 38 (`Is`).

Comment: For reference, the  [LinqPad](http://share.linqpad.net/8ed6g7.linq) test, but it uses my build of DotLisp, which I need to get around to publishing.